# Using POCO Types in a workflow

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation-4

I am working with WF4 and need to use Types I created before, in a Workflow, but I'm not sure of my strategy.

I have a class:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        //Constructor Logic
    }

    public void Connect()
    {
        //Connect to a TCP/Device for example
    }

    public void Disconnect()
    {
        //Disconnect from a TCP/Device for example
    }
}
```

and i want to use it in a WF4 Flowchart or StateMachine.

Then i have my main application:

```
class Program
{
    private MyClass myObject;
    WorkflowApplication WorkflowApplicationHoster;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       myObject = new MyClass;
       IDictionary<string,object> input = new Dictionary<string,object>() {{"MyClassInstance",myObject} };
       WorkflowApplicationHoster = new WorkflowApplication(new MyWorkflow,input);
        WorkflowApplicationHoster.Run();
    }
}
```

In my Workflow i have the "InArgument" -> "MyClassInstance" which is a MyClass Type and i use it for the whole workflow.

This doesn't feel correct.  How to use own classe with the WF4?

Comment: I cleaned it up, but I think you should [edit] and describe *what you are attempting to accomplish.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK -- so if I'm understanding this properly what you're trying to understand is how to get a new instance of your type into the workflow so it can be used. Generally speaking I've always been able to simply declare a variable and initialize it in some manner, but the question becomes what kind of initialization do you need?

If you just need to create a new instance of it, like shown above, then declare a variable of your type and in the Default Value issue the New {TypeName}() to create a new instance.

However, you're going to need to provide a lot more information if this doesn't help.

Comment: OK this helps! Now i used a variable to get "MyClass" into the Workflow. My problem is also that MyClass has events! how do i handle this events in the workflow? Is this possible? Or should i handle this events on the code side?

Comment: Events are a bit tricky.  You will need to handle them outside of the workflow with the host application and then use bookmarks to signal the workflow. See http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/wf4Callbacks

Answer (score 0):

You want to use that MyClass instance in global scope; is how I read this.

One popular way is to create it as a `Singleton`. Generally this means you have a private/protected constructor and a public `Instance` method that ensures that one and only one instance is ever created.

Another way is to make the class, and thus all it's methods, `static`.

There are multiple threads in StackOverflow on the topic of these approaches. Additionally, it seems the real argument is whether [to have something in global scope or not](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FRm3VPhseI), not necessarily *how* that's implemented.